# Is there a way to give boolean type as generic in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I have a code block like below:

```
public Interface ISupClass{
   void call();
   void call1();
   ...
}

public class NormalClass implements ISupClass{
   void call(){
     ....operations...
   }
   void call1(){
     ....operations...
   }
   ...
}

public class DailyClass implements ISupClass{
   void call(){
     ....operations...
   }
   void call1(){
     ....operations...
   }
   ...
}
```

Then I call them from main service like that;

Instances:

```
private INormalClass dailyClass = new DailyClass();
private INormalClass normalClass = new NormalClass();
```

Method:

```
public void call(int type, boolean isDaily){
  if(type == 0) {
   if(isDaily){
     dailyClass.call();
   }
   else{
    normalClass.call();
   }
  }
  if(type == 1) {
   if(isDaily){
     dailyClass.call1();
   }
   else{
    normalClass.call1();
   }
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to escape from isDaily check in above code block? Or how can I implement it effectively? I have just tried to implement with Java Generics but this doesn't look possible?

I know this looks like related with polimorfizm. But I wonder somethink like about it;

```
public Interface ISupClass<E>
  call(E type)
...
public class NormalClass implements ISupClass<Boolen.FALSE>
...
public class DailyClass implements ISupClass<Boolen.TRUE>
...
public void call(int type, boolean isDaily){
   supClass.call(isDaily);
```

Comment: For me, your question isunclear. What do you mean by "*escape from isDaily check*"? Could you share your generics approach? Have you tried using the wrapper class [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html)?

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what do you want it to do?

Comment: You want to learn about polymorphism here, not generics. That is the essence of OOP: the ability that "the same" method does different things, based on inheritance.

Comment: @Turing85, I've just edited it as what I mean about "generics approach" and "escape from isDaily".

Answer (score 2):

*(In case I understood what is the question)*

This is the point of using interfaces. Simply do something like this:

```
public class Example {
    public static interface ISupClass {
        void doSomething();
    }

    public static class NormalClass implements ISupClass {

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("I am a normal class.");
        }

    }

    public static class DailyClass implements ISupClass {

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("I am a daily class.");
        }

    }

    public static void doSomething(ISupClass clazz) {
        clazz.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething(new DailyClass());
        doSomething(new NormalClass());
    }
}
```

So, in your case instead of passing `boolean isDaily`, pass argument `ISupClass` in `call` method.

```
public void call(int type, ISupClass caller) {
    caller.call();
}
```

Now, generics is a totally different story and I am not able to see how it is related to the question.

Comment: passing dependencies in a method doesn't look right to me. You may provide these dependencies while constructing an object of the class where `call(int type)` is defined

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I don't disagree, but I think the question is... "how to avoid using the `isDaily` check". I don't think involving such kind of info in the answer will be helpful. I mean, is a totally different story as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,   `public void call(int type, boolean isDaily){...}` is an orchestrator/mediator method that manipulates the one or the other instance according to the flags received in the parameters.
In this case, why not use a `Map<Boolean, INormalClass>` to store the two instances in a way where you can retrieve them from a boolean key :

```
Map<Boolean, INormalClass> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(Boolean.TRUE, new DailyClass());
map.put(Boolean.FALSE, new NormalClass());
//...

public void call(int type, boolean isDaily){
  INormalClass obj = map.get(isDaily);
  if(type == 0) {
    obj.call();
  }
  if(type == 1) {
    obj.call1();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add default method to the interface:

```
public interface ISupClass {

    default void call(int type) {
        if (type == 0) {
            call();
        } else if(type == 1) {
             call1();        
        }
    }
    void call();
    void call1();
}
```

It leads you to following code:

```
public static void call(int type, boolean isDaily) {
    if (isDaily) {
        dailyClass.call(type);
    } else {
        normalClass.call(type);
    }
}
```